# NGINX Reverseproxy Problem: Publishing a Webapp behind a ReverseProxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have a "little" NGinx Problem.

I have Multiple Webapps and i will publish it through the NGINX Reverseproxy.

Under 1 URL i will publish multiple Webapps:

so:

```
https://Reverseproxy/webappA
https://Reverseproxy/webappB
https://Reverseproxy/webappC
```

This work so:

```
https://Reverseproxy/webappA --> redirect to http://www.webappaWebserver.com/webappA
```

--> And naturally this works fine ;-).

But with my Webapp B i have a challenge. I must find a way to bring the follow Scenario to work:

```
https://Reverseproxy/webappB --> redirect to http://www.webappBWebserver.com/
```

--> And this doesn´t work becuse the Subsite (after the Slash) is not there. But i can´t made URL Webserverchanges on this Webserver.

So how i can get this get running with this Constellation?

Here are my Config for the Reverseproxy:

```
  location /appb {
    proxy_pass              http://10.254.1.41:80;
    include                /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
  }
```

proxy.conf:

```
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

### Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Host              $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

### Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;
~
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- Replace page_name with webappA,webappB or webappC .
- Replace example.com with your subdomain.

  ```
    location /page_name/ { 
                    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
                    sub_filter_once off;
                    sub_filter_types *;
                    sub_filter /_elderjs /page_name/_elderjs;
                    proxy_ssl_verify off;
                    proxy_set_header Host "example.com";
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host "";
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "";
                    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
                    proxy_set_header Cookie "";
                    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                    proxy_pass https://example.com/;
                    proxy_redirect ~^(http://[^/]+)(/.*)$ https://$http_host$2;
     }
  ```

Its works for me ;). Hope this answer solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Jshi,

thanks for your Post. Unfortunatelly this doesn´t work. I have a blank page and in the Developer Tools of the Browser i see, that he try to get content from https://reverseproxy/content insted of https://reverseproxy/webappA/content